# Delete every other row in CSV file using AWK or grep

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep

I have a file like this:

```
1000_Tv178.tif,34.88552709  
1000_Tv178.tif,  
1000_Tv178.tif,34.66987165  
1000_Tv178.tif,  
1001_Tv180.tif,65.51335742  
1001_Tv180.tif,  
1002_Tv184.tif,33.83784863  
1002_Tv184.tif,  
1002_Tv184.tif,22.82542442  
1002_Tv184.tif,
```

How can I make it like this using a simple Bash command? :

```
1000_Tv178.tif,34.88552709    
1000_Tv178.tif,34.66987165    
1001_Tv180.tif,65.51335742  
1002_Tv184.tif,33.83784863   
1002_Tv184.tif,22.82542442
```

Im other words, I need to delete every other row, starting with the second.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hek2mgl's (deleted) answer was on the right track, given the output you actually desire.

```
awk -F, '$2'
```

This says, *print every row where the second field has a value.*

If the second field *has* a value, but is nothing but whitespace you want to exclude, try this:

```
awk -F, '$2~/.*[^[:space:]].*/'`
```

You could also do this with sed:

```
sed '/,$/d'
```

Which says, *delete every line that ends with a comma.* I'm sure there's a better way, I avoid `sed`.

If you really want to explicitly delete every other row:

```
awk 'NR%2'
```

This says, *print every row where the row number modulo 2 is not zero.* If you really want to delete every even row it doesn't actually matter that it's a comma-delimited file.

Comment: :) It's late and I must admit I'm (a little bit) drunken.. %) Why my one is not working? could swear it should work..

Comment: @hek2mgl yours didn't work because there *are* two fields. The second one is just empty.

Comment: Ahh OPs input did contain spaces after text.  If that is removed this does work, but not a very robust solution.

Comment: I guess Im just doing something wrong since nothing works.. Ill check my files, commands etc. Thank you very much!

Comment: It now works as well as other suggestions, I had to install GNU versions.

Comment: @user2966591 that's funny, because I don't have GNU awk or sed.

Answer (score 4):

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) provides a simple way

```
awk 'NR % 2' file.txt
```

Comment: Thant didnt do anything, sure it knows its CSV file?

Comment: @user2966591, this command would print odd lines to the standard output, which you could redirect to a file. Is that not what you need?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it wrote out the exactly same file.. Wired.

Comment: @user2966591 awk isn't a file editor. It operates on a stream. If you want to write to a file you have to use redirects. Try this: `awk 'NR % 2' file > newfile`. If `newfile` has what you want, replace the old file with it.

Comment: @user2966591 Or you might use `sed` as kojiro suggested and use the `-i` option (with care).. Note that `-i` is available in the GNU version of `sed` only. (common on Linux systems)

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '2~2d' file
```

or:

```
sed 'n;d' file
```

Comment: sed 'n;d', print the whole file :/

Comment: @user2966591: The `2~2` notation is GNU sed specific. The second alternative works everywhere I have tested it. What version of sed are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the `gnu sed` equivalent of the `awk` answers provided. Now you can safely use `sed`'s  `-i` flag, by specifying a backup extension:

```
sed -n -i.bak 'N;P' file.txt
```

Note that `gawk4` can do this too:

```
gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=".bak" 'NR%2==1' file.txt
```

Results:

```
1000_Tv178.tif,34.88552709
1000_Tv178.tif,34.66987165
1001_Tv180.tif,65.51335742
1002_Tv184.tif,33.83784863
1002_Tv184.tif,22.82542442
```

Comment: sed -n -i.bak 'N;P' gives blank file

Comment: @user2966591: The commands provided work fine for me using your input. Are you sure you're using the latest GNU `sed` and GNU `awk`?

Answer (score 1):

If OPs input does not contain space after last number or `,` this `awk` can be used.

```
awk '!/,$/'
1000_Tv178.tif,34.88552709
1000_Tv178.tif,34.66987165
1001_Tv180.tif,65.51335742
1002_Tv184.tif,33.83784863
1002_Tv184.tif,22.82542442
```

But its not robust at all, any space after `,` brakes it.
This should fix the last space:

```
awk '!/,[ ]*$/'
```

Comment: Test this `awk '{print "*" $0 "*"}'` to show is there are some blanks before or after the string.  This `awk '!/,[ ]*$/'` works fine on the test data above.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your help guys, but I also had to make a workaround:
Read it into R and then wrote it out again. Then I installed GNU versions of awk and used gawk '{if ((FNR % 2) != 0) {print $0}}'. So if anyone else have the same problem, try it!

Comment: Came here for this logic.  Just `FNR%2` will do it, `{print}` is the default action. The boolean equivalence of nonzero to true is concise. So `FNR%2{print}` but .. nope.  The first one's better, this is one-liner territory so [eschew](https://www.google.com/search?q=eschew) redundancy.